# Architecture: one or multiple databases for sub customers (web)APP

Tags: database, web-services, architecture

I've built a winforms application that i'm currently rebuilding into an ASP.NET MVC application using Web API etc. Maybe an app will be added later on.

Assume that I will provide these applications to a few customers.
My applications are made for customer accounting.
So all of my customers wil manage **their** customers whithin the applications I provide.

That brings me to my question. Should I work with one big database for al my customers, or should I use seperate database for each of my customers? I'd like to ask the same for web app instances, api's etc.

Technicaly I think both options are possible. If it's just a mather of preference, all input is appreciated.

Some pros and cons I could think off:

One database:

- Easy to setup/maintain
- Install one update for all of my customers
- No possibility to restore db for one customer
- Not flexible in terms of resource spreading
- Performance, this db can get realy large

Multiple databases:

- Preformance, databases are smaller sized and can be spread by multiple servers
- Easy to restore data if customer made a 'huge mistake'
- The ability to provide customer specific needs (not needed atm)
- Harder to setup/maintain, every instance needs to be updated seperately.
- A kind of gateway/routing thing is needed to route users to the right datbase/app

I would like to know how the 'big companies' approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be talking about database multi-tenancy, and you are right about the pros and cons.

The answer to this depends a lot on the kind of application you are building and the kind of customers it will have.

I would go with multi-tenant (single DB multiple tenants) database if

1. Your application is a multi-tenant application.
2. Your users do not need to store their own data backups.
3. Your DB schema will not change for each customer (this is implied in multi-tenant applications anyway).
4. Your tenants/customers will not have a huge amount of individual data.
5. Your customers don't have government imposed data isolation laws they need to comply with (EU data in EU, US data in US etc.).

And for individual databases pretty much the inverse of all those points.